# How to add tooltip to specific header column in primeNG table

Tags: html, angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-datatable

**Html**

```
<p-table #dt1 [columns]="cols" [value]="cars1">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let col of columns"> {{col.header}} </th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

**TS**

```
export class Table implements OnInit {

    cols: any[];

 ngOnInit() {
        this.cols = [
            { field: 'year', header: 'Year' },
            { field: 'brand', header: 'Brand' },
            { field: 'color', header: 'Color' }
        ];}}
```

**I want to display tooltip only for brand column**

*Using versions PrimeNG 9.2.1 on Angular 9.1.3*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can update cols to include some pTooltip value.

*component*

```js
 this.cols = [
    { field: 'year', header: 'Year' , tooltip: 'Year '},
    { field: 'brand', header: 'Brand' },
    { field: 'color', header: 'Color' , tooltip: 'Color of ‍♂️'}
  ];
```

*template*

```
<p-table #dt1 [columns]="cols" [value]="cars1">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
        <tr>
          <th *ngFor="let col of columns" [pTooltip]="col.tooltip"> {{col.header}} </th>
        </tr>
</ng-template>
```

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tabledynamic-tooltip?file=src/app/app.module.ts)

Answer (score 2):

Use primeNg tooltip [docs](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/tooltip)

```
<th *ngFor="let col of columns" [pTooltip]="col.field === 'brand' ? col.header : null"> {{col.header}} </th>
```

Instead of `col.header` after `?` place actual tooltip value as required.